# Masking middle characters in email before '@'

Tags: java, regex, kotlin, regex-lookarounds

I want to show only the first two and the last two characters of an email like the following:

```
Email -  123456789@gmail.com
result - 12*****89@gmail.com
```

I am using this regex to replace the matches with * - `(?<=.{2}).*(?=.{2}@)`.

Code snippet used:

```
String email = "123456789@gamil.com";
System.out.println(email.replaceAll("(?<=.{3}).*(?=.{3}@)", "*"));

// prints - 12**89@gamil.com
// Adds only 2 ** in the middle
// Required * for each replaced character like - 12*****89@gmail.com
```

Even though the regex matches the correct thing, It always replaces the middle part with `**`. But I want a `*` for each character. What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a regex isn't the best solution to this?⠀ If I had to maintain code like this (or especially like the more complex regex in the current answer), I'd be doing a lot more head-scratching (and probably code breaking) than if it used a simple `split("@")` &c — a bit more long-winded but far easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|^[^@]{2})[^@](?=[^@]{2,}@)", "$1*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W626oq/1).

- `(\G(?!^)|^[^@]{2})` - Group 1 (`$1`): end of the previous match or two non-`@` chars at the start of the string
- `[^@]` - any non-`@` char
- `(?=[^@]{2,}@)` - followed with 2 or more non-`@` chars up to a `@` char.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/aooEEI):

```java
String email = "123456789@gamil.com";
System.out.println(email.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|^[^@]{2})[^@](?=[^@]{2,}@)", "$1*"));
// => 12*****89@gamil.com
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, use

```kotlin
val s = "123456789@gmail.com"
val p = """^([^@]{2})([^@]+)([^@]{2}@)""".toRegex()
println(s.replace(p) { 
    it.groupValues[1] + "*".repeat(it.groupValues[2].length) + it.groupValues[3]
})
```

See [proof](https://ideone.com/cJnqIT).

Result: `12*****89@gmail.com`.

**Pattern explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]{2}                  any character except: '@' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]+                    any character except: '@' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]{2}                  any character except: '@' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```